# How to pass test outcome to different method in c# unit/integration tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing, mstest

I have bunch of unit/integration tests which creates a report after all the tests are run. At the moment i am passing in a hard coded response to the method that creates report.

How can i get the outcome of the test method? so that i can pass in this outcome as the response.

[image]

See how the test output shows us the Test Outcome i want to retrive that inside the test method. I know its possible. I have been able to retrieve the test name but couldn't get the outcome. Any help really appreciated.

Note: i am using normal MSTests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a test fails the `Test Method` is automatically aborted. You can use the `CurrentTestOutcome` property in the `TestCleanup` method.  If you want to take the StackTrace you have to put all the method's code inside a `try/catch` block.

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        // here you have access to the CurrentTestOutcome bot not on stacktrace
        if (TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Failed)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            // Your test code here
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // here you have access to the StackTrace
            TestContext.WriteLine(exception.StackTrace);

            // You can also add it to the TestContext and have access to it from TestCleanup
            TestContext.Properties.Add("StackTrace", exception.StackTrace);
            // Or...
            TestContext.Properties.Add("Exception", exception);

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but my static TestContext Type doesn't have a CurrentTestOutCome. Any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get test outcome you can use `TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome` property. You will get there `Passed`, `Failed`, `Unknown` values. As far as stack trace is concerned I think you should use `StackTrace` class.